# Linux: Using Proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have some struggles with the proxy settings.
There is a proxy server running which I use. So I've set the proxy urls in the environment based on this tutorial http://www.gtkdb.de/index_36_2111.html 
This works pretty fine if I use the chromium browser, but `ping`
and `apt-get` still does not work.
Did I miss something?
I guess `ping` and so on don't use the proxy settings of `env`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your problem referring to `apt` follow this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/109673/how-to-use-apt-get-via-http-proxy-like-this.

Ping uses ICMP and not http,https or ftp to do its job.

If you want ping to work you'll need to config the routing table of your machine as the proxy machine and config iptables on the proxy machine to NAT the traffic. To give you an idea follow this thread:
[how to transmit traffic from a linux vpn server to another linux server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177506/how-to-transmit-traffic-from-a-linux-vpn-server-to-another-linux-server/44182192#44182192)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok the first case is solved, but the second seems to require a lot more effort.